# Get Data from ArrayList Model class in android

Tags: android, arraylist, gson

I am using Gson library for pasring json,

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
   Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
  PropertyModel[] response = gson.fromJson(reader, PropertyModel[].class);
```

i had set all data in Araylist like

```
 Arraylist<PropertyModel[]> model=Arraylist<PropertyModel[]>();
 model.add(response);
```

Now My problem is i am not able to get Arraylist PropertyModel class data

Please suggest me how can get Value from ArrayList

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you getting any error? Did you try something like this PropertyMode[] pm=model.get(0)?   Please post also what kind of problem are you facing?

Comment: can you please post your adapter class and the class that contains the above code

Answer (score 1):

try this code it will probably work...

```
 String responseString = jsonArray.toString();
    Log.e("jsonArray string --->", "" + responseString);
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ModelOneVOneListItem>>() {
    }.getType();
    yourArrayList = new Gson().fromJson(responseString, listType);
```

Answer (score 1):

First add values in Arraylist . Assume your modelclass name is CorpusHeadingModel:

```
            ArrayList<CorpusHeadingModel> lemmaHeadingList = new ArrayList<CorpusHeadingModel>();

            CorpusHeadingModel headingModel = new CorpusHeadingModel();
            headingModel.setLemmaWord("Apple");
            headingModel.setLemmaOccurance("3");
            // now add the values to the list : 
            lemmaHeadingList.add(headingModel);
```

Now, Retrive one value with list position or any number corresponding the length of  lemmaHeadingList :

```
                CorpusHeadingModel model = lemmaHeadingList.get(position);// "position"  or any number value according to your lemmaHeadingList.size(). 

                String word = model.getLemmaWord();
                String countWord= model.getLemmaOccurance();

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "word=  " +word+"  Occurance= "+ countWord, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Output:

```
word= Apple  Occurance= 3
```

Hope, It helps, to retrieve any string from a list with modelClass.

Answer (score 0):

Your way is wrong assigning Array to Arraylist change last two lines:-

change these two line in the code

```
 Arraylist<PropertyModel[]> model=Arraylist<PropertyModel[]>();
 model.add(response);
```

to this:-

```
Arraylist<PropertyModel> model = new ArrayList<PropertyModel>(Arrays.asList(response));
```

For getting values you can use for loop

```
for(int i=0 ; i<model.size() ; i++){
    PropertyModel object = model.get(i);  //getting single object from Arraylist
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but how can i get model values

Comment: by model.get(indexValues); for any single index

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Add in Array list

```
ArrayList<String>() AddList= new ArrayList<String>();
Values = jb.getString("Your value");
 AddList.add(Values);
```

Then Convert Array List to String Array

```
String[] BrandNameArray = new String[AddList.size()];
BrandNameArray = AddList.toArray(BrandNameArray);
```

use the Array

Comment: Thanks for replay but how can i get model values

Comment: @AndroidControls, You can see my answer Below.

Answer (score 0):

as we know arraylist uses index to store values we must provide it an index but when its associated with a model class, it can be done in two ways.
let me give you an example.

1) you use your arraylist in the recycler adapter and get its object value using position,

```
 holder.name.setText(myarraylist.get(position).getName()); // for recycler adapter in "onBindViewHolder"
 name.setText(myarraylist.get(position).getName());//for base adapter in getview
```

2) if you want to check your object values in arraylist before passing it to the adapter you can do it this way,

```
 for (contact d :emps ){
 Log.e("name object of array",d.getName()+""); // getting the required object using the instance of model class
 }
```

where contact is the model class, which is also the type of the arraylist emps. I hope this helps you. good luck